# c# - send mass mailing with personalized link through Sendgrid with personally managed addressee list

Tags: c#, email, sendgrid

I have a C# website which uses a Dynamics CRM 2011 backend. The intent is that our client can use this website to create a HTML mail, preview it in the browser and then send it to a predefined CRM Marketing list. We plan on using Sendgrid to send our mails, but not to manage unsubscribes because we want to use a custom unsubscription implementation involving a footer in the mail with a link containing the ID of the customer that received the mail.

We don't want to manually create a mail for each of our contacts so we can put that ID in there. is there a way to tell Sendgrid through the API: "Here's a list of email addresses coupled to the IDs, we want you to replace this text in the footer with the ID corresponding to the email address you're sending it to"?

Comment: This is really a question you should direct to SendGrid support (or sales).

Comment: And I already did that, Mark, but I thought I'd ask it here as well, because there might already be a user who has done the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with [`substitution`](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/substitution_tags.html) tags in the [SMTP API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html) header or parameter.